# Parent menu and child menu vertical separator (unique, advanced)

Tags: css

I've the following navigation at http://www.roydukkey.com. The navigation is designed to have vertical separators between the parent menu and it's child menu. If you look under the 'Contact' menu-item it looks the way it's designed, however have a look under 'Projects'. The are vertical separators shouldn't exist where there aren't child items against the menu.

**How can the proper design be achieved through CSS alone?**

---

**This cannot currently be achieved through CSS.**

Here is the solution I've chosen:

```
// Naivagation Vertical Separator Counter
$("#main > ul > li > ul .level-has-sub").each(function(){
    $(this).find("> ul > li")
        .slice(0, $(this).find("~ li").length + 1)
        .addClass("vertical-separator")
});
```

Them simply style those items for the vertical separator.

Comment: On your local copy, try adding another list item to the contact sub menu.  I want to see if it is just the contact menu or if it is all of the sub menus.

Comment: All the sub menus. The Contact menu is fine because of the number of items and their position. It is responding to the same CSS as the other sub menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with pure CSS. You would have to count the number of `<li>`s in the child `<ul>`. If you restructured the menu, you could put the separators in the child `<ul>` instead. Then you would either a) show the separator on the left of every `<li>` in the child `<ul>`, or use `:first-child` to only show it on the first.

Comment: I will have to agree with @Mooseman - You cannot perform that level of codependency with just CSS. I tried some time on your site, it just doesn't work.

Comment: I've decided to close this question. Thanks you all for you conversation. The solution I've chosen is similar to @Mooseman's logic, and instead uses JavaScript to add classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this precisely, as CSS can't (yet) know the children count of another DOM-element.

CSS4 might be able to do this (ascend to the style's parent) in the near future: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject. This looks interesting too, although not pure CSS; http://demo.idered.pl/jQuery.cssParentSelector/. Maybe you can descend back down again after counting the children of the submenu, but that would be very complex to achieve with the low logical selection methods CSS has.

You could probably best do this in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com), but then it's not native CSS anymore, and then you might as well just fallback to JavaScript.

Here's an example of how style a style of a parent itself based on how many children it "at least" has;

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bus9p/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Contact 1.1</li>
            <li>Contact 1.2</li>
            <li>Contact 1.3</li>
            <li>Contact 1.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Contact 2.1</li>
            <li>Contact 2.1</li>
            <li>Contact 2.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    padding: 15px;
}

.submenu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 0px;
    border-top: 1px dotted blue;
}

.submenu li:nth-child(1) {
    border: 0px;
}

/* This style only happens if the menu has 4 or more children li's */
.submenu li:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.submenu li:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ li {
    border-left: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is minified so I cannot give you line numbers.

In you custom.css file replace

```
#main li li.level-open:after, #main li li.level-open~li:after {rules}
```

with

```
#main li li.level-open:after {rules}
```

Comment: I thought about that, too, but I strongly suspect that this won't solve the problem because now you have only one vertical seperator whereas the evolving menu might have more than one row, e.g. contact > test > columns

Comment: @hurrtz I tried it realtime using Chrome's Element Browser. It works.

Comment: Remember that what you draw isn't visible in the DOM itself (maybe in shadow-DOM?). For example if you want to access the look with JavaScript you explicitly need to call the style `:after`, which in some browser have issues updating "live" too. Check this fiddle and inspect the source on the `:after` content: http://jsfiddle.net/FRZw7/3/. You will not see any DOM-content available, only the CSS style that created those ninja-graphics ;)

Comment: @MiteshAshar Unfortunately, this isn't the desired effect. When I make the modification you suggest, only the first element of the sub menu has a vertical separator between its parent menu. All sub element should have vertical separators between its parent.

Comment: @roydukkey Please check if this is what you're trying to achieve https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1057626/Permanent/roys_menu.png

Comment: Correct. That one shouldn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions lays somewhere else then you might expect.

You have missed with expectation that on "Contacts" menuis all working well. I have added a new element just to show that the "`bug`" is in design of the menu.

[image]

So the problem is in the design of the drop down menu. To solve this , take a look in your css and look for

```
#main li li.level-open:after, #main li li.level-open ~ li:after
```

And delete line:

```
border-right: 1px dotted #7F7F7F;
```

Now, in order to achieve adding dotted menu you have to do change a little your php code. You can't do that in CSS. At least to my little research I couldn't find.

Create a new class - for example `.dotted-right-border` , and in you code, create an algorithm to add that css class to every element that will be printed on the left side of `li` when there is `li` element on the left.

**Update:**

Ok, then. I usually don't like to say that something is impossible, but in this case, and to my opinion here is impossible to do the change with pure CSS. Even current creating of menu items is adding `level-open` into HTML tag, so it would need something that will be doing around that. 
There could be one more approach for this situation, for example:

- To modify the class
  `#main li li.level-open:after, #main li li.level-open ~ li:after`

and change mentioned line:

```
border-right: 1px dotted #7F7F7F;
```

Into line:

```
border-right: 1px dotted transparent;
```

and then to set `border-color: #7F7F7F` for every new item under sub-menu, but then you couldn't tell apparent if the sub menu has it's match on the left side, so it would then show/not show dotted border. This is just an example approach. If I explained the approach good.

It all ends up into situation - `How can you tell apart if the sub menu has a parent item on the left side in order to show dotted border?` And that is why I think there is no pure CSS solution. But if someone knows better, then even better.

Comment: It seems there is a little confusion with my reference to the 'Contact' menu. I'm referring to this menu, with its current layout, as an example of the correct visual design (not code design). I realize I can achieve this by adding an additional (.dotted-right-border), but I wanted to pick your guise brains for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to answer to comment, but I have updated the answer to make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

CSS selector can not refer to children elements, the only class (pseudo) i know :empty. In your case at parent level you need information about number of children. The solution is to provide this info at design time and encode it (e.g. in class attribute).

Based on you code, for projects node you need to add info as follows:

```
<li class="level-has-sub limit">...</li>
<li class="level-has-sub limit2">...</li>
<li class="level-has-sub limit">...</li>
<li class="level-has-sub">...</li>
```

And corresponding CSS:

```
#main li li.level-open~li:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
right: -17px;
border-right: none;
z-index: 1;
}
// above is not necessary if you remove this selector from your css

/* main job */
#main li li.level-open:not([class*=limit])~li:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
right: -17px;
border-right: 1px dotted #7f7f7f;
z-index: 1;
}

#main li li.level-open.limit2+li:after, 
#main li li.level-open.limit3+li:after, 
#main li li.level-open.limit4+li:after
{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
right: -17px;
border-right: 1px dotted #7f7f7f;
z-index: 1;
}

#main li li.level-open.limit3+li+li:after,
#main li li.level-open.limit4+li+li:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
right: -17px;
border-right: 1px dotted #7f7f7f;
z-index: 1;
}

#main li li.level-open.limit4+li+li+li:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
right: -17px;
border-right: 1px dotted #7f7f7f;
z-index: 1;
}
```

As you can see, there is problem with multiple selectors like:

```
#main li li.level-open.limit2+li:after, 
#main li li.level-open.limit3+li:after, 
#main li li.level-open.limit4+li:after
```

You can workaround it by using coding by attribute substring, eg: limit1, limit11, limit111, and selectors [class*=limit1], [class*=limit11], [class*=limit111].

**Note:**
I use substring selector [class*=limit] witch is little unpredictable ;) you can change it to pair: [class^="limit"], [class*=" limit"] for better control.

Hope it helps :)